# how to reset final singleton object in flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, singleton

I'm facing an issue with `resetting a singleton` object in a `Flutter test`.

I have the following limitations that need to be taken into consideration while solving the problem:

> 1- The `_singleton` variable must remain `final`.
>
> 2- I cannot define a `static` or `public` method to change the value
> of `_lock` due to reduced security rules.
>
> 3- I must solve the problem within the `flutter_test` package and not
> any other package like `mockito`.

Here's the minimal code for the `Singleton` class :

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = Singleton._internal();

  bool _lock = false;

  Singleton._internal();

  factory Singleton() {
    assert(!_singleton._lock, "Singleton class has already been instantiated.");
    _singleton._lock = true;

    return _singleton;
  }

  static Singleton get instance => _singleton;
}
```

And here's the `test` that I'm trying to fix:

```
void main() {
  group('Singleton', () {
    test('should return the same instance', () {
      final instance1 = Singleton.instance;
      final instance2 = Singleton.instance;
      expect(instance1, same(instance2));
    });

    test('should throw an error when instantiated twice', () {
      Singleton(); // first instantiation
      expect(() => Singleton(), throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
    });

    test('should rest singleton and test pass', () {
      Singleton();
      expect(() => Singleton(), throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
    });
  });
}
```

**My question is:** How can I `reset` the `Singleton` object in the should reset the singleton and pass the test test while still adhering to the above limitations? .

Comment: You should stop using singletons and use riverpod providers instead, because in testing, providers can be created newly for each test using a new provider container, and can be overridden with other providers for mocking and tracing.

Comment: Thank you @randal-schwartz for your response. In this specific code, I would prefer to refrain from utilizing third-party libraries. Nonetheless, I genuinely appreciate the  concepts you have shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pleased to report that I've successfully resolved my issue.

I was able to devise a solution by creating a `public method` that detects the current `test environment`.In this case, except in the object test mode, it will not be able to be reset .

add below code to singleton class:

```
  void resetObject() {
    if (kIsWeb == false && Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')) {
      print("TEST MODE");
      _singleton._lock = false;
    }
  }
```

set changes in test code:

```
    test('should rest singleton and test pass', () {

       Singleton.instance.resetObject();  //add this line here

      Singleton();
      expect(() => Singleton(), throwsA(isA<AssertionError>()));
    });
```

If code is being run in a `web` environment, the program will continue to execute without encountering any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySingletonClass {
  static final MySingletonClass _singleton = MySingletonClass._internal();
  final int value;

  factory MySingletonClass() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  MySingletonClass._internal() : value = 22;
}

void resetitsingleton() {
  MySingletonClass._singleton = null; // Reset the singleton object
  MySingletonClass(); // Reinitialize the singleton object
}
```

You can call the resetitsingleton function whenever you need to reset the state of the singleton object in your app.

Comment: Thank you  @shahzeb-naqvi for your answer , but I cannot accept it for two reasons. Firstly, the variable `_singleton` is defined as `final` and therefore cannot be reset. Secondly, I intended to have a `reset` feature exclusively in `flutter_test` .